# How can I deal with multiple values in some attribute?

Tags: attributes, machine-learning, weka, data-representation

I'm using WEKA tool for clustering data analysis, however in some of my attributes, there are many values within the domain. Specifically, I need to represent some information about proteins and the information that I need to include is the terms associated with their functions.

For example these values are include on the same attribute "Function":

"RNA-Binding protein", "RNA bindingstructural constituent of ribosomerRNA binding", "translation", "intracellularribosomeribonucleoprotein complex".

And these terms diversify hugely.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

A common approach is to split categorical variables with `n` different categories into `n` binary dummy variables.

For example:

`gender = {male, female}` can be rewritten with 2 dummy variables as:

1. `male = [0, 1]`
2. `female = [1, 0]`

In your case, it seems a function can contain several distinct values (e.g. 1 protein with several functions). This is easy to mold into dummy variables too.